# WorldPay Payment Integration using PHP and direct XML method

Tags: php, payment-gateway, worldpay

I have been trying to set up the payment gateway using WorldPay for my client  using PHP, but i am unable to get any response from the World Pay server. And from where can i get the XML password? Is it the same as login password?

Below is the XML specification which I have been using to get the response from World Pay server

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay/DTD
WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN"
"http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="MERCHANTCODE">
    <submit>
        <order orderCode="T0211011" installationId="111111">
            <description>20 English Roses from MYMERCHANT Webshops</description>
            <amount value="100" currencyCode="GBP" exponent="2"/>
            <orderContent>
                <![CDATA[
                    <center>
                        <table>
                                <tr><td bgcolor="#ffff00">Your Internet Order:</td><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ffff00" align="right">T0211010</td></tr>
                                <tr><td bgcolor="#ffff00" colspan="3">Your billing address:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">Mr. J. Shopper<br><br>27b ParkView Mansions<br>47 Queensbridge Road<br>Chesterton<br>Cambridge<br>CB9 4BQ<br>United Kingdom</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                <tr><td bgcolor="#ffff00" colspan="3">Your shipping address:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">Mr.J. Shopper<br>47A Queensbridge Road<br>Cambridge<br>CB9 4BQ<br>UK</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                <tr><td bgcolor="#ffff00" colspan="3">Our contact information:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">MYMERCHANT Webshops International<br>461 Merchant Street <br>Merchant Town<br>ZZ1 1ZZ<br>UK <br>mymerchant@webshops.int<br>01234 567 890</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                <tr><td bgcolor="#c0c0c0" colspan="3">Billing notice:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="3">Your payment will be handled by WorldPay<br>This name may appear on your bank statement<br>http://www.worldpay.com</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
]]>
            </orderContent>
            <paymentDetails>
                <VISA-SSL>
                    <cardNumber>4444333322221111</cardNumber>
                    <expiryDate>
                        <date month="09" year="2019"/>
                    </expiryDate>
                    <cardHolderName>J. Shopper</cardHolderName>
                    <cvc>123</cvc>
                    <cardAddress>
                        <address>
                            <street>47A Queensbridge Rd</street>
                            <postalCode>CB94BQ</postalCode>
                            <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                        </address>
                    </cardAddress>
                </VISA-SSL>
            <session shopperIPAddress="213.137.19.45" id="0215ui8ib1" />
            </paymentDetails>
            <shopper>
                <shopperEmailAddress>jshopper@myprovider.int</shopperEmailAddress>
                <browser> 
                    <acceptHeader>text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</acceptHeader> 
                    <userAgentHeader>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)</userAgentHeader> 
                </browser>
            </shopper>
            <shippingAddress>
                <address>
                    <firstName>John</firstName>
                    <lastName>Shopper</lastName>
                    <address1>27b ParkView Mansions</address1>
                    <address2>47 Queensbridge Rd</address2>
                    <address3>Chesterton</address3>
                    <postalCode>CB94BQ</postalCode>
                    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                    <telephoneNumber>01234567890</telephoneNumber>
                </address>
            </shippingAddress>
        </order>
    </submit>
</paymentService>';
```

This is the URL to the Worldpay server.

```
 $url ="https://MERCHANTCODE:PASSWORD@secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp";
```

I have used the PHP curl function to get the response from the server.

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    if ( $result == false )
    {
    echo "fasle";
    }
    else    
    {   
    print_r($result);
    echo $result;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to spend some time reading the Worldpay documentation. You should be able to get a response from the server if you have the right credentials. Whether you're going about it the right way is another matter. Handling credit card data is a serious business. If you're not sure what you're doing you could end up being fined by the payment card companies. If in doubt, pay someone who really knows what they're about.

Comment: Thank you . But I spent considerable time reading the documentation regarding the XML direct method. Moreover, I have been using using the test environment of WorldPay to test the payment gateway.

Comment: Here I  wrote Very simple form integration to receive payment through WorldPay. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/worldpay-payment-gateway-integration-php/

Answer (score 0):

Only Woldpay can give you XML password and you cannot have an xml password until it has been proved that the site is pcidss compliant. There is a following way to implement the functionality without using XML. My suggested techniques are proven and i have implemented it into my site.

Remote Capture

```
<html>

<body>

<h1>Post-authorise a pre-authorised transaction</h1>

<br>This allows you to complete only those transactions you consider appropriate.

<form action="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/itransaction"; method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="instId" value="XXXXX">

<input type="hidden" name="op" value="postAuth-full">

<input type="hidden" name="authPW" value="YYYYY">

<input type="hidden" name="authMode" value="O">

<br>Enter the transaction ID to complete:

<input type="text" name="transId" value="" size="10">

<input type="submit" name="postAuth" value="Capture">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Remote Refunds

```
<html>

<body>

<h1>Issuing a full or partial refund</h1>

<p>This allows individual transactions to be refunded either fully or in part. Partial refunds must be issued in the currency the shopper originally used to pay.

<form action="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/itransaction"; method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="authPW" value="YYYYY">

<input type="hidden" name="instId" value="XXXXX">

<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="Refund">

<p>Refund type:

<select name="op">

<option value="refund-full">Full</option>

<option value="refund-partial">Partial</option>

</select>

<p>Enter the Transaction ID to refund:

<input type="text" name="transId" value="" size="10">

<p>Enter the amount (partial refund only):

<input type="text" name="amount" value="" size="10">

<p>Enter the currency (partial refund only):

<input type="text" name="currency" value="" size="3">

<input type="submit" name="refund" value="Issue Refund">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope that this has been of some help.